# Map same domain to two different AWS resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, aws-amplify

I have a domain `abc.io` in my Route 53.

I have a nextJS application in AWS amplify.
I have my marketing website on the EC2 server.

I wanted `abc.io` to open my nextJS application whereas `abc.io/w/*` opens the marketing website.

How can I configure my AWS to achieve that?

Comment: You could point the domain name to a load balancer and configure different targets, but that might be overkill (and involves extra expense). The easier solution is to use a subdomain (`w.abc.io`) that redirects to a different server.

Comment: Thanks but the subdomain is not my need.

Answer (score 2):

It's obvious that we can't do this directly with AWS Route53.

We can do it by other methods like:

1. Cloudfront with 2 origins and respective behaviors.
2. Custom nginx server to manage this, but for this, we need to configure SSL separately, either using self-signing or using some sort of proxying with the load balancer.

**Cloudfront Approach**:

- Create Distribution with amplify endpoint as the origin.
  [image: create cf distribution]
- Create an additional origin with your ec2 endpoints and name it `marketing`
  [image: create origin for marketing site]
- Create new behaviour with the custom path (replace `/test` with your path), and new origin `marketing`

  - use wildcard `/test/*` if you want all the sub path requests into new domain
    [image: create behaviour for specific path]
- Then wait for it to deploy
- Now all your requests will be forwarded to the default domain (amplify), except the custom path `/test` in this case, and `/test/` requests will be forwarded to marketing site.

Comment: I followed your steps. It worked for all of the cases except When I tried to browse `abc.com/w` which points to ec2(marketing website), it redirects to `ec2_public_dns/w`. Why is that?

Comment: did you place `/test/*` or `/test` in the custom behavior path?

Comment: I did it in the order:
0 -> /test ->ec2,
1 -> /test/* ->ec2,
2 -> /* -> nextJS amplify,
3 -> Default(*) -> nextJS amplify

Comment: if you've configured it in the order: 0 -> /w ->ec2, 1 -> /w/* ->ec2, 2 -> /* -> nextJS amplify, 3 -> Default(*) -> nextJS amplify

abc.com/w will fall under 0, and forwards the request to ec2, it's expected right?

Comment: Yes. But it is redirecting not forwarding. Why?

Comment: In that case, once check the network log, if this is caused by the CloudFront or your application, redirection happens if status_code is 302, once check from which url the 302 status code is coming, and what is the value of `location` response header.

Answer (score 1):

Use CloudFront. Create a CloudFront distribution with two behaviors and two origins. First, create two origins with one pointing at the marketing website and one pointing at the NextJS application. Next, you'll need to direct traffic to these origins with Behaviors. The first behavior should be for /w/* and point traffic to your marketing website origin. The second behavior should be for /* and point traffic to your NextJS app.

Then point your domain at CloudFront: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html

When you are done, Route53 will point to CloudFront. CloudFront will handle routing requests to the two origins based on the path in the request. You can even modify the request path to make it appear to the marketing website that requests to "/w/" are being passed to "/".